# Count number of rows after filter vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an excel sheet with few thousands rows of data. After applying a filter, there will be some rows filtered in between. My current code only counts the first few contiguous rows, the count stops even though there are more rows after it. How do I fix this?

Eg of row number after applying filter:

1

2

3

7

8

...

The count will only return 3. I am using the code below to do a row count.

```
print "Rows " & objsheet.Usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

Comment: Have you defined a value for the constant `xlCellTypeVisible` in your vbscript ?

Comment: yes, `const xlCellTypeVisible = &Hc`

Comment: Try `objsheet.usedrange.columns(1).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by Tim Williams in the comment.

`objsheet.usedrange.columns(1).specialcells(xlCellTypeVisible).count`